# Is there a way to execute a file from buffer instead of providing filepath?

Tags: node.js, stream, buffer, executable

In a standard way, we would exec a file in nodejs from storage with
 https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_execfilesync_file_args_options

I'm wondering if it could be possible to exec a file directly from memory without having to firstly save it to the disk?

The use would be in case you made a http request, get the file buffer, and instead of save it (via a pipe), you would exec it (via pipe or not).

```js
// the way it would be in case you save the file
fetch('https://assets-cdn.github.com/images/modules/logos_page/Octocat.png')
    .then(res => {
        const dest = fs.createWriteStream('./octocat.png');
        res.body.pipe(dest);
    });
```

Comment: you could use redis but you must JSON.stringify() it before that.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal link / example ?

Comment: https://redis.io/

Comment: ahah... I mean a link where redis is used to execute a file from its buffer. I only see that redis is used as datastorage.